# Where is the Available MBytes option in Windows 7 perfmon, that is in Win XP perfmon?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, memory, performance-monitor, perfmon

I don't know much about perfmon, but I see that Win XP has an option "Available MBytes"  under "Memory" after right clicking the graph and clicking "add counter". As shown in this screenshot

[image]

Where is the Available MBytes option in Windows 7 perfmon, that is in Win XP perfmon?

In Windows 7 perfmon I see this, screenshot below, but I cannot find an "Available MBytes" option, and I see no Memory category.

**Added**

Ass you can see below, there is no memory category

[image]

[image]

Comment: On Windows 8.1, when I expand the "Memory" category I see "Available MBytes" near the top and can add it. (I don't have any Windows 7 system handy.) Do you not see that? (Your screenshot doesn't show either way.) Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDAN2.png

Comment: @MichaelKjörling see screenshot added,  there seems to be no memory category listed

Comment: Well, that's definitely a bit more odd. Just for completeness' sake, you have tried as at least local administrator, right?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I don't think that's right as you don't run perfmon as admin, though I think perhaps a program that works with counters might have to be admin e.g. if it's creating a category and creating a counter.. though i'm no expert.  But certainly perfmon doesn't have to be run as administrator.

Comment: this may be the answer `lodctr /r` as mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980178/cannot-load-counter-name-data-because-an-invalid-index-exception   I then tried running a program that creates a category and a counter and increments the counter, running that program as administrator, and then I started perfmon and saw it. I think it was the lodctr /r that fixed the issue.

Comment: Running as admin (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit) I have Memory > Available MBytes showing. https://i.imgur.com/NnxYCAf.png

Comment: @DavidPostill and what about when not running perfmon as admin?

Comment: It's here too (Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, not run "as administrator").  Your WMI and/or Performance Counters may be corrupted..?

Comment: @barlop I don't have a non-admin account ...

Comment: @DavidPostill well, if you did then you could test the theory that admin has anything to do with it. I think, as techie said, it's nothing to do with it. Once I ran that lodctr /r command it fixed the category list. starting perfmon regularly is fine it shows them now. And I don't think running it as administrator would've made any difference.

Comment: @barlop <shrug> Too much effort. That's why it's a comment not an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work for me, and so may be the answer `lodctr /r' as mentioned here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980178/cannot-load-counter-name-data-because-an-invalid-index-exception

I then tried running a program that creates a category and a counter and increments the counter, running that program as administrator, and then I started perfmon and saw it. I don't think the program had anything to do with it. The program was giving an error until I ran lodctr /r.

I think it was the lodctr /r that fixed the issue(for perfmon and my program).

Since running lodctr /r, perfmon lists the categories fine e.g.

[image]

I would note also that it's just the name of a counter, and it's up to whatever program to increment it after every MB so, while it's good convention to use that one, technically one could use any counter.